# Why FlashTool isn't detecting firmware?

Tags: sony-xperia, 8.0-oreo, flashtool

I'm trying to flash stock Android 8 onto my Xperia X F5121.
Please see screenshots below:

[image: firmware files]

[image: phone is being detected to be in flash mode]

[image: firmware not being detected by FlashTool after selecting directory path]

What did I miss ?